# Pourquoi les enfants croivent-ils ?

Tags: conjugaison, enfants

Pourquoi les enfants disent-ils souvent 'croivent' pour 'croient' ? Il ne s'agit pas d'une irrégularité oubliée ('vous disez'). Et il n'y a aucun 'v' dans la conjugaison de 'croire'.

Comment: Je n'ai pas trouvé de tag 'erreur' ou 'incorrect'. Si vous en connaissez un, n'hésitez pas à l'ajouter.

Comment: [L’Académie française valide finalement « Ils croivent » et « Faut qu’on voye »](http://www.legorafi.fr/2014/05/21/lacademie-francaise-valide-finalement-ils-croivent-et-faut-quon-voye/) 

Comment: @jlliagre — pour être sympa avec ce·lles·ux qui ne connaissent pas le site à l’autre bout de ton lien : https://www.actualitte.com/article/zone-51/l-academie-francaise-deroule-le-tapis-rouge-au-gorafi-le-gag-immortel/53728

Answer (score 11):

Probablement parce que boire, un autre verbe du 3ème groupe en '-oire' qu'ils utilisent souvent a cette forme au présent / 3ème personne du pluriel.

Answer (score 11):

Comme le suggère vc74, les autres verbes en "-oire" et les verbes en "-oir" se conjuguent le plus souvent en "-oivent" à la 3e personne du pluriel:

ils doivent (devoir)
ils reçoivent (recevoir)
ils boivent (boire)

Il pourrait donc sembler logique de dire "ils croivent". Mais c'est incorrect, bien sûr.

Answer (score 10):

D'une manière plus générale, les verbes du troisième groupe dont la troisième personne du pluriel de l'indicatif présent se terminent en -oient (croire, voir et leur dérivés) sont anormaux.

Le français a deux schémas réguliers de variation de la racine d'un verbe dans sa conjugaison:

1. les verbes du 1er groupe à double racine comme jeter ou nettoyer, qui utilisent une racine (/ʒɛt/ /netwa/) pour les personnes du singulier et la 3P de l'indicatif, ainsi que pour le subjonctif, le futur et le conditionnel et une autre (/ʒət/ /netwaj/) pour les 1P and 2P de l'indicatif présent, l'imparfait et les participes
2. les verbes du deuxième groupe comme salir qui utilisent une racine courte /sali/ au singulier de l'indicatif présent, le futur et le conditionnel et une racine longue /salis/ au pluriel de l'indicatif présent, au subjonctif, à l'imparfait et au participe présent. L'infinitif et le participe passé sont assez problématique pour une telle analyse (est-ce que salir et sali sont décomposables en sali+suffixe /r/ ou nul ou sal+ suffixes /ir/ et /i/?)

Pour schématiser (et en excluant les formes littéraires apprises à l'école plutôt qu'acquises et les formes problématiques mentionnées plus haut):

[image]

Les verbes du troisième groupe, hormis quelques exceptions à une seule racine (courir ou offrir, par exemple) et d'autres complètement irrégulier (comme dire ou être) tendent soit à suivre le même schéma que les verbes du deuxième groupe, mais avec des futurs/conditionnels et des participes passés souvent imprévisibles (partir, lire, valoir ou dormir), soit à adopter un schéma à trois racines, avec une racine de l'indicatif présent singulier, une racine de l'imparfait aussi utilisée pour les première et deuxième personnes du pluriel de l'indicatif présent et une racine du subjonctif aussi utilisée pour la troisième du pluriel de l'indicatif présent (prendre, devoir, venir or savoir, par exemple)

[image]

Ce qui m'amène enfin à croire (et à voir), verbe du troisième groupe qui se conjugue... comme un verbe à deux racines du premier groupe:

[image]

La faute à la perte de la longueur dans les séquences voyelles+schwa, qui a rendu il croit et ils croient homophones, ainsi que je crois et je croie. Dans mon dialecte qui maintient cette distinction de longueur, croire est un verbe à trois racines classique:

[image]

Reste que pour un enfant en train d'acquérir le français, croire est une anomalie. Presque tous les verbes du troisième groupe distinguent clairement le pluriel et le singulier à la troisième personne de l'indicatif présent, ainsi que l'indicatif et le subjonctif. Avant que cette irrégularité ne soit intégrée, l'apprenant.e est incapable de prédire comment conjuguer croire à la troisième personne de l'indicatif ou au subjonctif. Il ou elle n'a que deux alternatives pour générer ces formes: se calquer sur les autres verbes du troisième groupe à deux racines et créer "ils croyent" sur la base de "ils croyaient" ; ou se calquer sur les verbes à trois racines et innover "ils croivent" en empruntant la forme, comme les autres réponses l'ont mentionné, de "ils boivent" ou de "ils reçoivent":

[image]

Il y a donc bien une raison structurelle qui amène à la création de ces conjugaisons alternatives, passé la simple analogie.